# Google Analytics tracking code is shown on homepage. how to remove it?

Tags: google-analytics

I've pasted my GA tracking code using a wordpress plugin called "insert headers and footers" and I can see my data in GA panel. But my problem is that the code is being shown on top of my home page and want to remove it from there. what should i do?

Comment: What does "shown" mean?  Do you mean that it is visible to users, or do you mean that the code is in the source code of the home page and you want to remove it from that particular page?

Comment: it is visible to users.

Comment: That means it isn't properly installed.   I don't know anything about that particular insertion plugin.  I've used "Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights" plugin before and gotten it to work.

Comment: I tried out the Headers and Footers plugin about two years back, and it worked well. I'd check if it's still actively supported; try a similar plugin, as WP has a few that do the same thing; and also make sure you pasted the whole GA snippet and there aren't any tags or brackets missing.

Comment: Can you give us a link to your site ?

Comment: Many of these tools still require you to wrap your header tags.  I.e., `<meta name="google-site-verification" content="your code" />`  Is your verification code wrapped similarly?

Comment: Check that you are not using a caching plugin and a seperate plugin that minifies scripts. Doing so can lead to similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

The tracking code that you need to paste in the header should look similar to this

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-TRACKINGID"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-TRACKINGID');
</script>
```

Not just the tracking ID.

Since the text is within `<script></script>` it should not be displayed on the front-end.

You can find this tracking code in `Google Analytics` > `Admin (Gear Icon)` > under Property `Tracking info` > `Tracking Code`